# How to properly implement padding for Seq2Seq LSTM in PyTorch?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, seq2seq

In this [PyTorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_generation_tutorial.html), they did not use padding despite having variable length input and output. It seems to work fine, but how? Shouldn't we implement padding if input is of variable length? What is the proper way to go about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You are correct. The input tensor should be padded if the batch size is more than 1 and the sequences are of different sizes.
But the example generates the input tensor as

```py
def inputTensor(line):
    tensor = torch.zeros(len(line), 1, n_letters) # <-- (<sequence_length>, <batch_size>, <input_dim>)
    for li in range(len(line)):
        letter = line[li]
        tensor[li][0][all_letters.find(letter)] = 1
    return tensor
```

In pytorch's RNN, LSTM and GRU, unless `batch_first=True` is passed explicitly, the 1st dimension is actually the sequence length the the 2nd dimention is batch size.

The example is just to show the flow, but yes I think they should have put a small note about this.